# Find path in a binary Tree with particular sequence

Tags: tree, binary-tree

> Given a binary tree where each node has a value and a sequence of numbers, you have to find that does the tree contain any path that has that particular sequence of numbers in that order

I Stumbled upon [this question](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-experience-for-sde-internship-on-campus/) on GFG while reading one of the interview experiences. only this was the question and no else data given. Is there any approach to solve this problem or any similar kind of question exists with all the data?

Comment: I don't think this problem is well defined. How is the path defined? Does it always start from the root or can it be between two arbitrary numbers? Also what does this mean "does the tree contain any path that has that particular sequence of numbers in that order"?

Comment: What exactly is `GFG`?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? This is not a C++ related question. It's purely about an algorithm. Also, I have a hard time understanding the question. "_Given ..., **you have to find that does the tree contain any path that has that particular sequence of numbers in that order**_" - what does the last part mean? Is it a translation error?

Comment: @KoushikJ Do _you_ understand the question? I looked at the original post and I don't. I think the person who wrote this post about an interview experience didn't get all the details that were presented quite right in the post. I would just drop it (unless you actually _do_ understand what it is that they are asking - and in that case, please explain it in your question).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think each node has some value say numbers. There is another data where they give some sequence of numbers. I think probably you have to traverse through the nodes of tree to find if that sequence exists.

Comment: it's still not very clear what problem that person was asked to solve, which makes your question unclear too. Perhaps you should drop the reference to that question and explain in your own words what you want to do - and also try implementing it and share your code with us. That way, your question can probably be answered.